# Blazor, call function and pass control as a reference in parameter

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor, razor-pages

I am creating a Blazor app and trying to render an input

```
<input id="block1_role1_names" @onchange=@(async(e) => await update_details("block1_role1_names", e)) value="@getContact("block1_role1_names")" class="NameColumn" />
```

It is working as expected but I have to pass the id value multiple times to different functions, for example "block1_role1_names" is mentioned 3 times, Is there any way to pass reference of current control to update_details and getContact function and get ID from the control?

I have 50 textboxes, I don't want to pass Id value 3 times for every input control.
Dynamically generating the control is the last option for me but trying to avoid.

Comment: Can you share how `id` is been used in `update_details` and `getContact`?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to avoid having a loop to display your 50 textboxes ? If yes, you could create a Blazor component and give the HTML id as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you could use a RenderFragment something like this:

```cs
@InputControl("block1_role1_names")

@InputControl("block2_role2_names")

@code {
    private RenderFragment<string> InputControl => (value) => (__builder) =>
        {
            <input id="@value" class="form-control mb-3"
            @onchange=@( (e) => this.UpdateDetails (value, e)) 
            value="@GetContact(value)" />
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid what you already had the best option.

In blazor onchange event, we could see that the event is `ChangeEventArgs` which only contains the propery of the current input value, we couldn't get the current DOM, nor the DOM id.

```
public class ChangeEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the new value.
    /// </summary>
    public object? Value { get; set; }
}
```

If you have different onchange method for the 50 textboxes, then since they are  1-to-1 binding, we could hardcode the id inside the onchange function, but I trust all of the 50 textboxes are using the same function which is `update_details`.

I have an idea which might be a workaround. Just like you know blazor also has data-binding. We can have 50 variables for the 50 textboxes, and the variables could be defined with the id. Normally, we always has a model to include all the variables because they might belong to the same form. What I have below is just a sample, and we usually have `public FormModel inputModel { get; set; }` instead. But it looks not so good as well. Or we might use the `@ref` to reference the InputText, but it still requires 50 variables. So I think passing id as the function parameter is the best option.

```
<InputText id="input1" Value="@inputVauleForInput1" ValueChanged="NameChanged" ValueExpression="() => inputVauleForInput1" @ref="input1Ref"></InputText>

@code{
    public string inputVauleForInput1 { get; set; }
    public InputText input1Ref;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        inputVauleForInput1 = getContact("input1");
    }

    private void NameChanged(string value)
    {
        if (input1Ref != null)
        {
            var id = input1Ref.AdditionalAttributes["id"];
        }
        inputVauleForInput1 = update_details("input1");
    }
}
```